Should classical/traditional ML techniques such as polynomial regression/decision trees/random forests SIGNIFICANTLY outperform RNN in timeseries?
I have a dataset of numerous years of buoy wave height measurements including features such as measured significant wave height, numerical model predictions, peak wave period, mean wave period, and wind components yet when I plot regression models and hierarchical models, they significantly outperform RNN-based models such as GRU, LSTM, BiLSTM (0.09m MAE compared to 0.2).
RNN-based models were given the option of having 1-3 layers with each 50-150 neurons with a dropout rate of 0.2, 0.5, and batch sizes of 32, 64, and 128. I haven't tried mixing them together as the grid-search already takes significant time.
Additionally, I even tried passing into the RNNs the ML corrected height with an MAE of ~0.09m but with no improvement.
The data format being passed into the model is a sliding window of the previous X hours predicting the next Y hours, then shifting/sliding the window by 1 hour.
[1,2,3] predicts [4,5]
[2,3,4] predicts [5,6] etc

So the target variable is the recorded significant wave height and the model receives the following features:

numerical model prediction (this is replaced by the regression model correction in one of the attempts)
mean wave period
peak wave period
wind components

I am by no means an expert on this so any feedback/help would be greatly appreciated.
Edit:
Thanks for the initial feedback. I'll keep trying to play around with the model and go back to the default settings.
For some additional information that may help, I have compared the ML corrected wave height in the training data (lets call it feature1) with the target and got a mae of 0.09 as seen in the plot:
The data is scaled using the minmax scaler and fed to the model with the following structure:
def build_recurrent_model(
look_back,
num_features,
num_layers=2,
units=50,
dropout_rate=0.2,
activation='relu',
layer_type='LSTM',):

#Input layer
input_layer = Input(shape=(look_back, num_features))

#Accomodate different RNNs
if layer_type == 'LSTM':
    recurrent_layer = LSTM
elif layer_type == 'GRU':
    recurrent_layer = GRU
elif layer_type == 'BiLSTM':
    recurrent_layer = lambda units, activation, return_sequences: Bidirectional(
        LSTM(units, activation=activation, return_sequences=return_sequences))
else:
    raise ValueError("Invalid layer type. Choose from 'LSTM', 'GRU', 'BiLSTM'.")

#Process through the recurrent layers
x = input_layer
for i in range(num_layers):
    return_sequences = (i < num_layers - 1)  # Only return sequences for all but the last layer
    x = recurrent_layer(units, activation=activation, return_sequences=return_sequences)(x)
    x = Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)

#Output layer for forecast horizon which will always be 24
output_layer = Dense(24)(x)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001, clipvalue=1.0)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse')

return model


Additional Information: The prediction window has to be 24 hours or more in the future. Using just 1 hour (taking the first element of the prediction arrays) gives a very good result but is not the desired outcome

I think you should start with some basic debugging of your deep learning code. Check that you can overfit a single batch of data into perfect predictions. Tweak the parameters of the optimization algorithm, etc. My first guess is that there is a small bug in either how you specified the architecture or the optimization.

Here is a great guide https://karpathy.github.io/2019/04/25/recipe/ . Pay close attention to section "2. Set up the end-to-end training/evaluation skeleton + get dumb baselines". I think this could pinpoint the issue quickly

@GuillaumeDehaene Thank you for the help, I highly appreciate it. I'll have a play with trying to overfit the training dataset (might try first without validation data) and then go from there. I'm not super familiar with custom optimizers so I used the Adam with the clipping to prevent exploding gradients for the weights. I also adjusted the post to include the model construction code if it helps pinpoint any obvious errors. The guide you sent is amazing and I will go through it!!

Possibly related

COULD BE
The immense flexibility offered by a deep learning approach gives enormous ability to fit complex trends.
Polynomial regression can do the same, if you offer enough flexibility (which I will concede is less straightforward than doing so with deep learning). This relates to the Stone-Weierstass theorem.
A deep learning approach also has a few factors working against it.

With the immense flexibility offered by a deep learning approach comes immense ability to overfit.

The numerical optimization is its own art, and the various hyperparameters related to this can afect how strong the trained model winds up being. This can lead to a model that seems more flexible having worse in-sample performance, which is not how it works in, say, ordinary least squares linear regression where we have a closed-form solution.


Therefore, it is not obvious that the deep learning approach must be better than a more classical approach.

Thank you for your comment. I understand that the incomparable flexibility of DL models should dominate over vanilla/classical models which is why I decided to post this question. Training the model purely on training data resulted in overfitting with an MAE score of the "best" regression (polynomial) model score. I guess the next step now is to figure out how to keep the accuracy of the model while reducing underfitting on the validation/testing set!!

@DonaldM. I understand that the incomparable flexibility of DL models should dominate over vanilla/classical models This isn’t quite true. Stone-Weierstrass is in the same spirit as the neural network universal approximation theorems, that, technical conditions aside, a polynomial can approximate a decent function as well as we want, same as a neural network can approximate a decent function as well as we want.
